# "Expecting miMATRIX type" error when reading MATLAB MAT-file with SciPy

Tags: arrays, matlab, numpy, scipy, mat-file

This is a MATLAB question: the problem is caused by interactions with MATLAB files and Python/numpy.  I am tying to write a 3-D array of type uint8 in MATLAB, and then read it in Python using numpy.  This is the MATLAB code that creates the file:

```
voxels = zeros(30, 30, 30);
....
fileID1 = fopen(fullFileNameOut,'w','s');
fwrite(fileID1, voxels, 'uint8');
fclose(fileID1);
```

This is the Python code that tries to read the file:

```
filename = 'File3DArray.mat'
arr = scipy.io.loadmat(filename)['instance'].astype(np.uint8)
```

This is the error that I get when I run the python code:(I think this is the source of the problem.  What is MM

```
raise TypeError('Expecting miMATRIX type here, got %d' % mdtype)
```

This is the output of the Linux command 'file' on the 3D array file
that I created (I think this is the source of the problem.  What is MMDF Mailbox?):

```
File3DArray.mat: MMDF mailbox
```

This is the output of the same Linux command 'file' on another 3D array file
that was created by someone else in MATLAB:

```
GoodFile.mat: Matlab v5 mat-file (little endian) version 0x0100
```

I want the files I create in MATLAB to be the same as GoodFile.mat (so that I can read them with the Python/Numpy code segment above).  The output of the Linux 'file' command should be the same as the GoodFile output, I think.
What is the MATLAB code that does that?

Comment: `file` looks at (among other things) the first few bytes of a file and compares them against magic strings. This is likely the reason it is identifying your file as a "MMDF mailbox", whatever what is. Your first few bytes of data just happen to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a MAT-file, use the MATLAB [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) command:

```
voxels = zeros(30, 30, 30, 'uint8');
save(fullFileNameOut, 'voxels', '-v7')
```

You need to add `'-v7'` (or `'-v6'`) as an argument to `save` to create a file in an older format, as [SciPy doesn't recognize the `'-v7.3'` files](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) created by default.

Comment: Okay.  But the error mentions 'v5'.  Should I use a '-v5' argument?

Comment: Okay '-v6' worked (there is no '-v5' option).  Thanks.  I never would have figured that out on my own.

Comment: To read v7.3 matlab in python, use [h5py](https://docs.h5py.org). For example, `import h5py; f = h5py.File( 'my.mat', 'r' ); x = np.array( f.get( 'data/x' ))`